# My isLoggedin variable in React can be change from client side. How to secure my site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

Well i am new to React. While developing a simple website i came accross an issue. I used a isLoggedin variable in React app to check if it is true then the user can access the whole website otherwise he will remain in the login page. But when i came to know that my isLoggedin variable can be easily changed from client side to true, so how can i secure my webite that only the logged in user can access it? How make isLoggedin variable secure?
Note: isLoggedin is a state variable.
And my frontend is connected to a nodejs backend. When a user login I sent a request to backend to verify and return a token. After receiving the token i make isLoggedin to true. Thats my logic.

Comment: instead of a simple boolean, maybe provide the logged in user with a token and the token is used to authorize actions and other requests?

Comment: It's this a frontend-only project or do you have a secret of server of some type?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain more. Kindly review it.